# Efficient C++ data structure to search for intervals in sets of integer values

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure (and an C++ implementation) that allows to search (efficiently) for all elements having an integer value within a given interval. Example: say the set contains:

3,4,5,7,11,13,17,20,21

Now I want to now all elements from this set within [5,19]. So the answer should be 5,7,11,13,17

For my usage trivial search is not an option, as the number of elements is large (several million elements) and I have to do the search quite often. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` on a `set`? Providing you can hold all the integers in memory, that would seem a potential solution.

Comment: If your data set is static, just use a sorted array and binary search (followed by linear enumeration or a second binary search).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, you typically use `std::set`, that is an ordered set which has a search tree built on top (at least that's one possible implementation).

To get the elements in the queried interval, find the two iterators pointing at the first and last element you're looking for. That's a use case of the algorithm `std::lower_bound` and `upper_bound` to consider both interval limits as inclusive: `[x,y]`. (If you want to have the end exclusive, use `lower_bound` also for the end.)

These algorithms have logarithmic complexity on the size of the set: O(log n)

Note that you may also use a `std::vector` if you sort it before applying these operations. This might be advantageous in some situations, but if you always want to sort the elements, use `std::set`, as it does that automatically for you.

<kbd>[**Live demo**](http://ideone.com/taf80o)</kbd>

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Your set (Note that these numbers don't have to be given in order):
    std::set<int> s = { 3,4,5,7,11,13,17,20,21 };

    // Your query:
    int x = 5;
    int y = 19;

    // The iterators:
    auto lower = std::lower_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), x);
    auto upper = std::upper_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), y);

    // Iterating over them:
    for (auto it = lower; it != upper; ++it) {
        // Do something with *it, or just print *it:
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5
7
11
13
17
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could be much faster to use std::set::lower_bound() instead of std::lower_bound, assuming that std::set::lower_bound() iterates down the tree to find the element matching the criteria, while the std::lower_bound() algorithm cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

For searching within the intervals like you mentioned, **Segment trees** are the best. In competitive programming, several questions are based on this data structure.

One such implementation could be found here:
http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-segement-tree/

You might need to modify the code to suit your question, but the basic implementation remains the same.

Comment: This searches in a set of intervals. The question is about a search in a set of numbers given an interval.

Comment: When I read the wikipedia article for segment trees, it seems to me it's not the right thing. Following wikipedia, a segment tree is a data structure to store intervals and to query for point (thus if the intervals contain the point). But I want to do the thing vice versa. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: A segment tree stores segments and answers point queries. The OP is asking just the converse, storing points and answering interval queries. For the latter, a standard search tree is appropriate.